# how can we create full stack application like frontend backend and database one docker image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-image

I'm beginner in docker can anyone help me in  how can we create full stack application like frontend backend and database one docker image

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Usually a full stack application is deployed as 2-3 containers. One with the database, one with the backend and one serving the frontend files.

Comment: i didn't start yet. I am asking that how can i create the one image of full project mean frontend backend.

Comment: If I was doing this and really wanted as few images as possible, I'd compile my front-end to static files, and bundle them into my main server application (maybe using something like the Go `"embed"` package).  But I'd still run a separate database container.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a recommended to host all in one container. Usually one service will have it's own container. Let's take an example suppose you are using following for your app

- Backend (Php or NodeJS or Python)
- Frontend (Vue or React)
- Database (Postgres Or Mysql)
- Caching Service (Redis or Memcache)
- Webserver (Apache or Nginx)

This is just an example. Here you will create individual container for Backend, Frontend, Database, Cache and WebServer. This will ensure that your services will not fail due to any other dependencies and also this will encapsulate/isolate the containers and error handling is more easier. You will usually communicate between apps by exposing ports.

But sometimes you might want to share some data between two service. eg: If you are using your local machine for file storage then you might want the folder to be given access to Backend and Webserver (for exposing assets). In this case you will use volumes for this.

**TLDR:** If you absolutely want to host it in a single dockerfile then you can use **multistage build** for this and use a ubuntu or alpine container and install all the package you need and expose the ports.

Comment: I want for my experience and also a task for me. now i want to ask how can i build this where will be the docker file build and how i give different folder files in one docker file.

Comment: I think you want to use docker-compose. If not then follow the steps from here https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container

Comment: Just for clarity, since the frontend runs in the user's browser, you wouldn't create a container for that. The frontend files will be hosted in the webserver container.

Comment: @UsmanTariq if you want a real example then go to this link https://github.com/jbfink/docker-wordpress/blob/master/Dockerfile

Comment: @HansKilian not necessarily the case. In case of SSR you need to create a container